# Dynamic generating of robots.txt in Laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

I have multiple domains set up in laravel and each domain needs different sitemap.

I am generating file like this in robots.blade.php and adding sitemaps I will use.

```php
User-agent: *
Disallow:

@foreach($sitemaps as $sitemap)
Sitemap: {{$sitemap}}
@endforeach
```

And in RobotsController.php it is like this:

```php
    public function b2bRobots()
    {
        $data = [
            'sitemaps' => [
                route('b2b.sitemap')
            ],
        ];

        return response(view('robots.robots')->with($data), 200, [
            'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'
        ]);
    }
```

And I have deleted robots.txt from public directory.
This code is working on localhost. But I want to ask whether it will be working for bots(like googlebot) or they will ignore it? And how can I know that they are not ignoring it?

Comment: As long as a bot can get to your `robots.txt` they won't have any clue how it was generated. So, as long as you've got a `Route::get('robots.txt')` pointed at this controller function, it should do.

Comment: @ceejayoz yes I have route `Route::get('/robots.txt', [RobotsController::class, 'b2bRobots'])` Thank you for confirmation.

Comment: If this is working locally, what makes you think that it could not work on any other system? What have you tried to check for differences?

Comment: @NicoHaase I didnt know if I would need some special Content-Type or something like that, it is now on production I think its working correctly at least google search console says nothing bad